# jsPlumb: Avoiding multiple connectors between divs

Tags: jsplumb

Experts,

I'm using jsPlumb to connect divs with multiple endpoints. I'm trying to prevent multiple connectors between the same two divs. So for example, if I have divs A, B, C, connectors between A and B, A and C are ok but not two connectors between A and B (using different endpoints).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot of your code, but you can do something like this:

```
var exampleEndpoint = {
    reattach:true,
    scope:"yourScope",
    isSource: true,
    isTarget:true,
    beforeDrop:function(params) { return !checkExistingLinks(params.sourceId,params.targetId); }
};

function checkExistingLinks(sourceId, targetId) {
    var flag = false;

    jsPlumb.select({source: sourceId}).each(function(connection) {
        if(connection.targetId === targetId) {
            flag = true;
        }
    });

    return flag;
}
```

That is, you need to identify a connection attempt and then verify if the elements involved already have a connection. jsPlumb.select() returns for you a list (or map) of this connections.